# C Lua Bindings Windows VS2017

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

I would like to build a .dll filled with Lua bindings written in C compiled using VS 2017, but I don't seem to be having any luck, and the resources available to me are confusing and, by majority, outdated.

Here is what I've done.

I've already compiled lua from source and added it to my path so that I can `lua.exe` anything. This also created `lua53.dll`.

I've taken all of the .c and .h files of the lua source and added them to my VS project, along with one `main.c` which I am using to test. I added the .dll file as well, but only in the same way that I added the .c and .h files. I don't think it's doing anything.

Here's main.c:

```c
#define LUA_LIB

#include "lua/lua.h"
#include "lua/lualib.h"
#include "lua/lauxlib.h"
#include "tg/tg.h"

static int lua_TG(lua_State *L) {
    return 1;
}

static int lua_useTGHandle(lua_State *L) {
    struct TGHandle *tgHandle = malloc(sizeof(struct TGHandle));
    *tgHandle = TG();
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, tgHandle);
    return 1;
}

static const luaL_Reg tglib[] = {
    {"TG", lua_TG},
    {"useTGHandle", lua_useTGHandle},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

LUALIB_API int luaopen_libtg(lua_State* L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, tglib);
    return 1;
}
```

One function implemented, one not, but the lib should register.

I have changed the build type to a .dll, and I get the .dll generated without any errors, but when I try to use it in a Lua script I get:

```
%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Surely I just have no clue what I'm doing. How would I just set up a lua-binding-building environment in VS2017?

Comment: Does bitness of your .dll (32/64) matches to the bitness of your .exe?